# How to invalidate browser cache after logout from the node js application

Tags: node.js, express

I have developed an application in node js and express. I wish to invalidate the browser cache after the user logs out of the application . The main reason being that the user should not be able to see the earlier loaded page when he clicks on the back button.

Comment: You can instruct the browser to never cache your page either with the right http headers when the page is served or with `<meta>` tags in the HTML.

Comment: ^ But maybe you can conditionally set the headers based on whether user is logged in or not. (`if(req.user)..`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can conditionally set the headers to never cache your page based on whether user is logged in or not.

This express middleware will do just that:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
        res.header('Expires', '-1');
        res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
 app.use((req, res, next) => {      
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store')
    next() 
 })
```

in my `app.js` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine in chrome but in Safari it won't work.

```
//import nocache module

const nocache = require("nocache");

//create a middleware incentral place like app.js or index.js to register for all routes. that's it.

app.use(nocache());
```